# what is the special regarding int :0 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
struct S {
    char a;         // location #1
    int b:5,        // location #2
    int c:11,
    int :0,         // note: :0 is "special"
    int d:8;        // location #3
    struct {int ee:8;} e;   // location #4
};
```

It seems that int :0 member variable of a struct does not occupy any memory space, and it is marked as: // note: :0 is "special"

Does anybody know what is the special usage of int :0 here? Thanks

PS: sample code is quoted from http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#memory-model

Comment: Do you know what bit fields are? If you do, it's unclear to me what you are asking. A bit field with 0 bits should trivially not occupy any space, and giving it a name is pointless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int:0;` declares a zero-width bitfield.

This occupies no memory, but explicitly separates the bitfields declared prior to it from the bitfields declared afterwards into separate memory locations.

This may potentially introduce padding into your structure, but this can be important for concurrent accesses.

In your example, `b` and `c` occupy the same memory location, so you cannot have one thread access `b` while another accesses `c`. On the other hand, the zero-width bitfield ensures that `d` is a separate memory location, so `b` and `d` can be accessed concurrently from separate threads without synchronization.

Without the zero-width bitfield, on 32-bit or 64-bit platforms, it is likely that the compiler would make `b`,`c` and `d` part of the same machine word, so safe concurrent access would be impossible without special instructions whereas with the zero-width bitfield, the compiler would ensure that they are stored in separate machine words, or appropriate instructions are used to ensure that concurrent access is safe.

Answer (score 4):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

> The value zero is only allowed for nameless bitfields and has special
>   meaning: it specifies that the next bit field in the class definition
>   will begin at an allocation unit's boundary.

Answer (score 1):

And, to quote from the original C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882, First Edition 1998-09-01, Section 9.6 "Bit-fields" [class.bit] para 2).

> As a special case, an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero specifies alignment of the next bit-field at an allocation unit boundary. Only when declaring an unnamed bit-field may the *constant-expression* be a value equal to zero.

The *constant-expression* mentioned in the last is the width of the bit-field.

To date, every subsequent C++ standard (and draft) has identical wording.  Which may, at least in part, explain the *0 is "special"* note.